# wpf prevent second click button

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a problem again. when I click button, window appears. when I click button again same window appears again. I want when I click button first time, page appears. **but I want to prevent second click.** can anyone help me with this problem? thanks in advance.

```
private void Dictionary_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
  dic.Show();
  dic.Topmost = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a simple boolean value to check if the window is already open?

```
private bool isWindowAlreadyOpen = false;
private void Dictionary_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (!isWindowAlreadyOpen)
   {
       Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
       dic.Show();
       dic.Topmost = true;
       isWindowAlreadyOpen = true;
   }
}
```

Should do the trick.

**EDIT**
You'll have to register the closed event of the window to unset the boolean:

```
private bool isWindowAlreadyOpen = false;
private void Dictionary_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (!isWindowAlreadyOpen) 
    {
        Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
        dic.Show();
        dic.Topmost = true;
        dic.Closed += Dictionary_Closed;
        isWindowAlreadyOpen = true;
    }
}

private void Dictionary_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isWindowAlreadyOpen = false;
}
```

**EDIT2**
Alternatively, you can use `dic.ShowDialog()` if you want this window to be topmost and only one instance.

Comment: i tried it. it works. but when i close the window and wanna open again, i doesnt open. can you have any idea about it? 
thanks all.

Comment: thank you very much. it worked. i an new in wpf and .net. thank you again. good working.